# Optimum Order of Filter in contaharmonic mean filter

Tags: image, image-processing, filtering

I am working on a set of images with different levels of noise and bias fields. I want to apply Contra-Harmonic Mean filter in order to remove noise but I am stuck at a point where not able to choose value for Q ie Order of Filter. 
I already know the theoretical knowledge that positive value removes the pepper noise and negative for the salt noise.

I will be thankful if I could know more about, how to choose the optimum value for Q before coding my filter.

Comment: The optimum surely depends on the images. So what you want is a data driven automatic selection of the optimum? This is more a topic for statistics, less for programming.

Comment: If it depends upon the image then how to choose the its value ? I've gone through the standard books as well but its not mentioned anywhere that how to choose the appropriate value of Order of the Filter.

Comment: One way is to choose by visual inspection, that is you look at the results for different orders and if you like them, the order was the right order.

Comment: Yeah !!! that's the one I've already though about but there must be some technically proved method.

Comment: Well, you can define a quality measure (figure of merit) which you then optimize (i.e. you search for the filter order that gives the highest figure of merit). So how probable are pepper and salt noise, respectively, in your image? What do you know about the noise?

Comment: I do not have much knowledge about type of noise because its a synthetic data and available with the different noise levels (like 1%, 3%, 5%, &% and 9%). These is no information given about type of noise. I tried it with -2 and +2 and +2 is giving better results. But I want to be sure that the final value I'll be using( let it be any positive or negative value ) will be better compared to others.